# Display laravel chatify user images in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, chat

I am trying to display user image added in chatify messanger in my blade view, thank you in advance.

Blade file:

```blade
@foreach($users as $user)  
    <div class="d-inline p-2">
        <div class="col"> 
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; background-color: #162238; color:white;">
                <br/>
    
                <!--<img id="nature" src="{{asset('avatars/default1.png')}}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='avatars/default1.jpg';" class="imogi" style="width: 80px; border-radius: 20%" alt=""/>-->
                <div class="card-body" style="background-color: #162238; color:white;">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="background-color: #162238; color:white; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:24px;color:red"></i> {{$user->name}}</h5>
                </div>
                
                <ul class="list-group list-group-light list-group-small" style="background-color: #162238; color:white;">
                    <li class="list-group-item px-4" style="background-color: #162238; color:white; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{$user->organization}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item px-4" style="background-color: #162238; color:white; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{$user->location}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item px-4" style="background-color: #162238; color:white; text-align:center; color:#3490dc;"><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> joined {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</li></small>
                </ul>
                
                <button style="background-color:black;" onclick="window.location.href='/chatify/{{$user->id}}'" type="button" class="btn position-relative">
                    Message <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering that's different from the outcome you're looking for? We can't answer your question unless we know both **what you want to happen** and **what's actually happening**. Can you edit your question to add any error messages you may be seeing, or if there are none, describe why your code doesn't work as you intend?